# Convert array value to variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Hello I am trying to convert the value of an array to a variable.

I have a class named X as follows:

```
    class x{

        public static function getData(){
            $data = array(
                 "start" => '$id',
                 "end" => '$name'
            );
            return $data;
        }

}
```

The getData function returns the array:

> array (size=2)
>   'start' => string '$id' (length=3)
>   'end' => string
>   '$name' (length=5)

I have function as follows in another class:

```
$id=10;
$name = "kheshav";    
$data = x::getData();
var_dump($data);
```

What i want is to ressolve the `$id` and `$name` values in the array to its corresponding variable.
So that end result will be as follows:

> array (size=2)
>   'start' => int 10
>   'end' => string 'kheshav'
>   (length=7)

I tried the following code but with no hope:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = eval("\$value =\"$value\";");

}
```

Comment: pass your values to function

Comment: This solution work i must admit but The issue is that i can have multiple variable and passing them as parameters can be hectic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the conventional way to do this would be to pass the data into the function:

```
class x{

    public static function getData($id,$name){
        $data = array(
             "start" => $id,
             "end" => $name
        );
        return $data;
    }

}


$id=10;
$name = "kheshav";    
$data = x::getData($id,$name);
```

Comment: Tis solution work i must admit but The issue is that i can have multiple variable and passing them as parameters can be hectic

Comment: @KheshavSewnundun Well that is how variable scope works, and for good reason. You could defeat the point of variable scope and use the `global` keyword, but that is not a good idea

Comment: Yes sure its of another scope and hence unaccessible but is there a way be looping through the array and assigning the value of the array to its corresponding variable. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should parameterize your `getData()` function as follows:

```
    public static function getData($id, $name){
        $data = array(
             "start" => $id,
             "end" => $name
        );
        return $data;
    }
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
$id=10;
$name = "kheshav";    
$data = x::getData($id, $name);
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works as I have mentioned in other comments, but, however,the issue is that i can have multiple variable.is there a way by looping through the array and assigning the value of the array to its corresponding variable. Thank you in advance